# Como verificar se todos os objetos estão presentes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Existe algum método no ruby que verifica se todos os objetos estão presentes? Seria algo para evitar o seguinte uso:

```
if @stretch_source.present? && stretch_target.present?
```

Ou esta seria mesmo a forma mais correta?

Answer (score 1):

Eu ia colocar isso em comentario mas não tenho rep o suficiente.

Você quer verificar se todos os objetos estão presentes onde?
Tem como verificar em um array.

```
[@stretch_source, stretch_target].all?(&:present?)
```